# Spotify URL string error in browser "response_type must be code or token"

Tags: swift, api, spotify

I was building a Spotify clone app for my project in which used the authorization guide for making a URL String to perform the URL request. To test the URL I printed it in my console and after opening the link in my browser it gave me the error as

"response_type must be code or token"

it should be showing me the Spotify login page but showed up this instead.

here is my URL String

```
 let srting = "\(baseUrl)?response_type=code&client_id=\(Constants.clientId)&scope=\(scope)&redirect_uri=\(redirectURI)"
```

Comment: What do you have as the baseUrl e.g. accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=\(Constants.clientId)&scope=\(scope)&redirect_uri=\(redirectURI) should be a valid URI for example (also should start with https:// but not included to make comment easier to read)

Comment: this is what I'm having in the base URL "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response"

Comment: i have HTTPS in mybase url

Comment: the problem its showing in the browser is with response_type

Comment: Okay, good to check the base URL just in case, just to be sure it doesn't have that extra "response" bit. Otherwise can't think of anything that would cause that error myself

Comment: The base URL is perfectly fine